# Is "Part of being a good teacher is to build..." grammatically incorrect?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

In the sentence:

> Part of being a good teacher is to build a warm and comfortable connection with your students.

Why did my teacher say it should be

> To be a good teacher, it's important to build a warm and comfortable connection with your students.

Comment: Both are fine. You should ask your teacher for clarity. Part of being a good student is asking the right questions.

Comment: I don't think the original sentence is correct.  "Part of X is to build"?  That doesn't sound at all fluent to me.  "Part of X is *building*" sounds much more natural.

Comment: @stangdon - I wondered about the 'being' followed by a to-infinitive, but found this _In the panel’s view, a fundamental part of being a teacher is to record marks accurately, and Mr Laughton had failed to do so on a number of occasions._ (part of a [judgement](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1018776/Mr_Colin_Laughton_Professional_conduct_panel_meeting_outcome.pdf) of a UK teacher disciplinary panel)

Comment: It may be that your teacher didn't like "part of being X is to build". I might write "Part of being a good teacher is building a warm connection..." if I wanted to keep the first part of the sentence.

Comment: Maybe I'm OCD, or perhaps it's my former legal employment but I should mention that in a UK context, my use of 'judgement' above was a spelling error. Here, a legal context requires 'judgment' (i.e. what courts, tribunals, panels, judges, etc deliver), and everywhere else 'judgement'.

Comment: You'll need to ask her. The difference is a matter of style, and to some extent meaning (for example the first doesn't use the word "important").